# Why isn't require() working for my constants exported into a node.js modules?

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, node-modules, ts-jest

I am trying to run this test in Jest:

```
test("find the earliest start", () => {
  expect(findEarliestStart([ex.TS2])).toBe(ex.TS2.start_time);
  expect(findEarliestStart([ex.TS5, ex.TS2, ex.TS6])).toBe(ex.TS5.start_time);
});
```

I have this require in the test file:
`const ex = require("constants");`

I get the error that TS2 is undefined, specifically "TypeError: Cannot read property 'start_time' of undefined".

In constants.ts I have:

```
const TS2: Timeslot = 
{start_time: 940,
  end_time: 980,
  day: "Wed",
  term: "2"
}

const TS5: Timeslot = 
{start_time: 180,
  end_time: 210,
  day: "Wed",
  term: "2"
}

const TS6: Timeslot = 
{start_time: 250,
  end_time: 310,
  day: "Wed",
  term: "2"
}
```

and

```
module.exports = {
  TS2:TS2, TS5:TS5, TS6:TS6
}
```

The function findEarliestStart looks like this:

```
/**
 * return the earliest start time out of all timeslots
 * @param {Timeslot[]} lots 
 */
export const findEarliestStart = (lots:Timeslot[]): Time => {
  if(!lots.length){
    throw new Error("cannot find earliest start of empty array");
  };
  return lots.reduce((min:number, ts:Timeslot) => {
    return (ts.start_time < min) ? ts.start_time : min
  },
  Number.MAX_VALUE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of, Hello and Welcome on stackoverflow, @ptellier!

**TL;DR**: use`const ex = require("./constants");` with "./" in front of the constants.

The `require` in node has some syntax to be aware of. Normally, it is used to `require` components and modules from external packages, installed using a package manager. In this case, the name of the corresponding package is supplied as an argument. If the package is part of a namespace, it starts with `@namespace/packagename`, otherwise it is just the `packagename`.

To load local files, you have to tell node that you are looking for a local file instead of a package. You can do this by using relative path prefixes like `./` for files in the same directory as the current file or `../` to start in the current folders parent directory.

Since you were missing the path prefix, node loaded its internal `constants` module, which apparently has no `TS*` properties, which is why they were `undefined`.